# NIFI - Disable Client Certificate Request

Tags: certificate, apache-nifi

I'm using nifi 1.11.4.  I have https and simple ldap setup on nifi, however, it still asks for a client certificate when navigating to the page.  If i select a certificate it fails, which is understandable, due to not setting up client certificates.  If i cancel, it will go to the login screen.

Is there any way to make it not check for client certificates, since I am using ldap to login?

I saw some properties about turning them off, but those properties seem to be gone.  I checked the documentation and it seems to mention that it will ask for a client certificate unless another authentication method is setup.  However with ldap still setup, it is still asking for a certificate.

login-identity-providers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>        
    <loginIdentityProviders>
        <provider>
           <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
           <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
           <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>
   
           <property name="Manager DN">CN=blah,OU=USERS,OU=LAW,DC=na,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com</property>
           <property name="Manager Password">secret</property>
   
           <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
           <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>
   
           <property name="Referral Strategy">IGNORE</property>
           <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
           <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>
   
           <property name="Url">ldaps://ldapserver.na.ad.test.com</property>
           <property name="User Search Base">OU=USERS,OU=LAW,DC=na,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com</property>
           <property name="User Search Filter">sAMAccountName={0}</property>
   
           <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
           <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
       </provider> 
    </loginIdentityProviders>
```

nifi.properties file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Core Properties #
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.count=
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms 
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.queue.backpressure.count=10000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=1 GB

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.wal.implementation=org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.partitions=256
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=2 mins
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key=

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000
nifi.swap.in.period=5 sec
nifi.swap.in.threads=1
nifi.swap.out.period=5 sec
nifi.swap.out.threads=4

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=1 MB
nifi.content.claim.max.flow.files=100
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=12 hours
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=../nifi-content-viewer/
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key=

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.debug.frequency=1_000_000
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key=

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=24 hours
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=1 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=30 secs
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false
# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are:
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uuid, mime.type
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is retrieved.
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=2


# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component Status Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=lawdev1
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=lawdev1
nifi.web.https.port=9443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=secret
nifi.security.keyPasswd=secret
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=secret
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=
nifi.security.needClientAuth=false

# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=

# Apache Knox SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.knox.url=
nifi.security.user.knox.publicKey=
nifi.security.user.knox.cookieName=hadoop-jwt
nifi.security.user.knox.audiences=

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.dn=NONE
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.kerb=UPPER

# Group Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing group names coming from external sources like LDAP. The following example
# lowercases any group name.
#
# nifi.security.group.mapping.pattern.anygroup=^(.*)$
# nifi.security.group.mapping.value.anygroup=$1
# nifi.security.group.mapping.transform.anygroup=LOWER

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=true

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=lawdev1
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11443
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=4
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi

# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster management
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=

# analytics properties #
nifi.analytics.predict.enabled=false
nifi.analytics.predict.interval=3 mins
nifi.analytics.query.interval=5 mins
nifi.analytics.connection.model.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.analytics.models.OrdinaryLeastSquares
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.name=rSquared
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.threshold=.90
```

Thanks,
Dusty Ryba

Comment: Can you share your `nifi.properties` and `login-identity-providers.xml` files? You are likely missing a setting to completely configure LDAP authentication.

Comment: If you have a certificate in your browser then its always going to prompt to ask you if you want to use it

Comment: I don't mind the certificate being asked, but problem is if you select it, it locks you out from getting to the server.  you have to close out and select cancel to get the login to prompt.

Will edit to add in nifi.properties and login-identity-provider.xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
nifi.security.needClientAuth=false
```

for old version of NiFi.

In new version:
NiFi’s web server will REQUIRE certificate based client authentication for users accessing the User Interface when not configured with an alternative authentication mechanism which would require one way SSL (for instance LDAP, OpenId Connect, etc). Enabling an alternative authentication mechanism will configure the web server to WANT certificate base client authentication. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security_configuration

So I think that disabling is imposible.

Comment: Code-only answers are usually considered low-quality. They are unlikely helping anyone

Comment: Code-only answers aren't necessarily low quality. See, e.g. [What comment should I add to code-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300837/1364007). If it's possible that the code would solve the problem and OP would accept the answer, it's now low quality. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29340975).